# GCP - Migrating data from bucket to Datalab instance storage

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I have a Cloud Datalab VM which I understand has some persistent storage.  I have some data stored in a GCP bucket.  Questions:

1) Does the Cloud Datalab VM persistent storage provide better performance than the GCP bucket?
2)  How do I migrate the data from the bucket to the Datalab VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [regional storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes#regional) class for the [GCS buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#buckets), it have almost the same performance as compared with the [persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs). You can also check various parameters mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#gcsbuckets), which describes the specialty of GCS buckets as well.

As mentioned in [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets) help center article you can easily connect your GCS bucket with any GCP resources, local machines and other cloud services etc.

Migrating/transferring data to/from the GCS buckets is the most easiest task. You can use  [gsutil command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) to achieve this.

Additionally, you can also seek the help of ‘[Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/)’ if you are planning to perform a data transfer from external cloud service(ex:AWS S3 bucket) to a GCP storage bucket.